# Error when running python script in node js with python-shell npm

Tags: python, node.js, opencv

I am developing a web application which has image processing functions. So I used opencv-python and implemented the python script to node js using python-shell package,

**index.js;**

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

var options = {
    mode: 'text',
    pythonOptions:['-u'],
    scriptPath:'C:/Users/MB/PycharmProjects/NumberPlate/venv/Lib/site-packages',
};

PythonShell.PythonShell.run('./myScript.py', options, function (err, results) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('finished: %j', results);
});
```

**myScript.py** (first few lines);

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'


# Read the image file
image = cv2.imread('./t30.jpg')

# Convert to Grayscale Image
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Canny Edge Detection
canny_edge = cv2.Canny(gray_image, 170, 200)
```

All my imports, environment variables and image path are ok and when I run `myScript.py` it works well and gives me the output.

**Error is:**

```
 ----- Python Traceback -----
    File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\NumberPlate\venv\Lib\site-packages\platedetection2.py", line 11, in <module>
      gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) {
```

Error comes only when executed with `python-shell`
What could be the issue and is it ok to run opencv scripts via python-shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the error by giving the full path of the image in the python script to imread()